# Get progress for site - loading scripts & libraries

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, client

I have quite a bunch of script and libraries that I am using in my website, which takes like 5 to 8 seconds to load.
ex.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/js/overdo.js"></script>
```

I want to show a loading bar till all the scripts have been loaded, can anyone guide me on whats needs to be done for that?

Comment: How do you know it takes 5-8 seconds for those script tags to load? Sounds like a very long time and more probable that you are confusing script loading time with other parts of page load

Comment: ran a check with for users with minumum bandwidth 200kbs ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very simple approach you can use in case when all the scripts you want to load are loaded synchronously (you don't use modules loader, async attributes, etc) - like in your example.

The trick is add progress indicator script the *very first* on the page, before all your heavy scripts. It is also make sense to inline this script (because it shouldn't be too big ideally):

```
<script>
// some progress bar implementation progress.show()
console.log('showing progress, loading bar, etc.');
</script>

<script src="../lib_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../lib_components/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../lib_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib_components/lodash/dist/lodash.min.js"></script>
<script src="../scripts/js/overdo.js"></script> 

<script>
// hiding loading bar
console.log('scripts loaded')
</script>
```

Now, for the implementation of the actual progress bar, it's up to you how and what to render. However, remember that depending on where you put those scripts DOM tree might not be loaded yet (if scripts are in `<head>`). I would anyway recommend to place scripts before closing `</body>`. The ideal structure for this approach would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!-- some styles, no scripts here -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/styles.css" />
</head>
<body>

  <div class="loading" hidden>Loading...</div>

  <!-- Some application HTML code -->

  <script>
    // show/create progress/loading
    var loading = document.querySelector('.loading')
    loading.hidden = false
  </script>

  <!-- many script tags ... -->
  <!-- ... -->

  <script>
    // hide/remove progress/loading
    loading.parentNode.removeChild(loading)
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```